# JIRA CLI: Viewing currently configured workflow --steps

Tags: linux, shell, jira

Does anyone know of a shell command to view currently configured progressIssue steps?

Answer (score -1):

```
JIR="$JIRA_LOCATION -s $SERVER --password $JIRA_PASSWORD --user $JIRA_USER --issue "$JIRA_Project-$JIRA_Number""


$JIR -a getAvailableSteps
```

Lots of examples [here](https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JCLI/Examples).